# How to redirect and login to another specific url from codeigniter 4 to codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I am working on admin panel for diff. states in codeigniter 4.Admin login will be single for all states. From login page admin will enter username, password and choose state for which he wants to login. All this is working fine. But for single state admin is in codeigniter 3 and if i merge the code with all states then i need to update it in codeigniter 4.So, i want single login like if admin will choose CI3 state from login page then it will login into CI3 dashboard. Users table is same for all states. But when i am trying to redirect to CI3 dashboard it's not working. I am not able to set session for CI3 admin in CI4 admin login controller. Users table is same for both admin panels. This is my code which is in CI4 login controller.

```
if ($validation) 
{
  $userstate = $this->request->getPost('userstate');
  $email=$this->request->getPost('email');
  $password=md5($this->request->getPost('password'));
  $data = $userModel->where('e_mail', $email)->first(); // matching email from database users table
  if($data)
  
    $pass = $data['pass_word'];
    $getState = explode(',', $data['user_state']); 
  if($password == $pass)
  {
    $ses_data = [
    'admin_id'      => $data['user_id'],
    'user_name'     => $data['user_name'],
    'e_mail'        => $data['e_mail'],
    'userType'      => $data['user_type'],
    'user_state'    => $userstate,
    'logged_in'     => TRUE
    ];
    $this->session->set($ses_data);         
    if($data['user_type'] == 'admin' || $data['user_type'] == 'state user')
    {

        if($userstate!="MA")
        {

        return redirect()->to($userstate); // this will redirect to CI4 admin dashboard according to states
        }else{
        return redirect()->to("http://localhost/CI3/dashboard"); // only this will redirect to CI3 admin dashboard 

        }

    }   
  }else{
    $this->session->setFlashdata('error', 'Wrong Password');
    return redirect()->to('login');
    die();
  }
}else{
    $session->setFlashdata('error', 'Email does not exist.');
    return redirect()->to('login');
    die();
}
}else{
    $this->session->setFlashdata('error', $this->validator->getErrors());
    return redirect()->to('login');
    die();

}
```

Comment: is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Bear in mind that CI4 sessions use a different Key. If you look at your Session ID's on your CI3 area vs CI4 you'll see the difference. This only occurred in recent 4 releases so you could either use an older CI4 (never ideal / advisable) or alter the SessionHandler in question to remove the `$this->idPrefix`. I think that should get things working.

Comment: No they are now incompatible

Comment: so we can not get CI4 session on CI3 page?

Comment: okay Is there any other way i can use single login page for CI4 and CI3 dashboard?

Comment: You'd need to amend the framework directly - if you're using Database for your sessions then you'd amend the DatabaseHandler and lookup the `$this->isPrefix`. You'll also need to make sure your Session cookie names are the same between both environments. Why must you keep the v3 system? Is it not possible to upgrade it?

Comment: Actually this admin panel have lot of functionality. If i will upgrade to CI4 then i need to work again on complete code from directory structure to model, view, controller.

Comment: Also can you please told me if CI 3.1.11 is compatible with php 8.2. I have done a lot of R&D. where in some articles i have found that CI3 is compatible with php 8.x but not sure about it.

Comment: I'm not sure either I'm afraid - its been a while since I've worked with CI3.